# Connecting from webserver to SFTP server / firewall issues

Tags: server, sftp, firewall, flysystem, thephpleague

I am trying to connect to a remote SFTP server via Phpleagues Flysystem.

The remote SFTP server's firewall only allows the IP address of our webserver.

In my understanding, when a client accesses our website an API request from the client is sent to our backend webserver. This webserver in turn is sending a request to the remote SFTP server. However, this does not seem to work and I assume that the request being sent from our webserver is sent with the client's IP address (instead of the one from our webserver).

Is there an option to sent the internal request from webserver to SFTP server with the IP address from our webserver in order to pass the firewall?

(It does work when I am sending a request from our company network, whose IP address is also registered in the firewall of the remote SFT server. As soon as I try from another network, the same request fails.)

Comment: The SFTP connection originates **from the webserver** (= from the machine that runs Phpleagues Flysystem code). If the connection does not work, then it's most likely a networking problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: thanks, @MartinPrikryl this is also what I thought how it works. then I need to investigate what the issue is...